# Need Logic in Selenium - Using loop

Tags: java, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver, automation

Need help in Automation - How to write Automation code for below,

**One of the website consists many travelers.  It can be just one, 2 or 3**

[image]

It should check People Insured

```
if (condition1) {
      // block of code to be executed if condition1 is true
    } else if (condition2) {
      // block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is true
    } else {
      // block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is false
    }
```

Condition 1 = if People Insured consists only 1 traveler,
Condition 2 = if People Insured consists 2 travelers
and so on..

[image]

like that, it should check with names...  doesn't matter with title or names..

It should check no. of lists tag and proceed with that code..

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: And what is the issue?